# Keep 3d model facing the camera at all angles

Tags: xna, c#, camera, models

I'm trying to keep a 3d plane facing the camera at all angles but while i have some success with this:

```
Vector3 gunToCam = cam.cameraPosition - getWorld.Translation;
Vector3 beamRight = Vector3.Cross(torpDirection, gunToCam);
beamRight.Normalize();
Vector3 beamUp = Vector3.Cross(beamRight, torpDirection);
shipeffect.beamWorld = Matrix.Identity;
shipeffect.beamWorld.Forward = (torpDirection) * 1f;
shipeffect.beamWorld.Right = beamRight;
shipeffect.beamWorld.Up = beamUp;
shipeffect.beamWorld.Translation = shipeffect.beamPosition;
```

*Note: Logic not wrote by me i just found this rather useful

It seems to only face the camera at certain angles. For example if i place the camera behind the plane you can see it that only Roll's around the axis like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sLfy.png (imagine if you are looking from behind where you have fired from.

Any idea what to what the problem is (angles are not my specialty)

```
shipeffect is an object that holds this class variables:
public Texture2D altBeam;
public Model beam;
public Matrix beamWorld;
public Matrix[] gunTransforms;
public Vector3 beamPosition;
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with XNA anymore, but isn't there a Matrix.LookAt() function available?

Comment: i tried Matrix.CreateLookAt but it resulted in the model displaying flat with no moment :(

Comment: Interesting, well there are many ways to do this, and I don't feel like re-posting the answer (many people have the same problem) so here is a like to a similar post: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15070/orienting-a-model-to-face-a-target