# Rotating 3d plane to XY plane

Tags: java, matrix, rotation

I have a triangle in 3d space and would like to create a grid over the triangle, such as in the image below.

[image]

The purpose of this is to store information about each block of the grid. In order to store this grid in a 2D array, my idea was to rotate the triangle until it is in the XY plane. After rotation the above triangle would look like the image below.

[image]

What I have tried to do is find the angle between the triangle's normal and the z-axis, then rotate each vertex by this amount.

```
    public double getAngle(Vector3 normal, Vector3 axis) {
        double dot = normal.dotProduct(axis);
        double angle = Math.acos(dot / (normal.getMagnitude() * axis.getMagnitude()));
        System.out.println("angle = " + Math.toDegrees(angle));
        return angle;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector3 pointA = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        Vector3 pointB = new Vector3(5,5,5);
        Vector3 pointC = new Vector3(-5,5,5);
        Triangle tri = new Triangle(new Vector3[]{pointA, pointB, pointC});
        Vector3 normal = tri.normal();
        normal.normalize();
        Vector3 zAxis = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        Matrix4x4 rot = Matrix4x4.getRotationMatrix(0, 0, patch.getAngle(normal, zAxis));
        for(int i = 0; i < tri.vertices.length; i++) {
            tri.vertices[i] = rot.multiply(tri.vertices[i]);
        }
    }
```

The result of this code would be:

```
Triangle's normal: (0.0, -50.0, 50.0)
Normalized normal: (0.0, -0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865475)
Vertices after rotation:
   (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
   (4.440892098500626E-16, 7.0710678118654755, 5.0)
   (-7.0710678118654755, 4.440892098500626E-16, 5.0)
```

This is not quite right, though. I am expecting all z-coordinates to be the same so that I can ignore them and store the grid in a 2d array. Is there something else I need to do to rotate the triangle appropriately, or is there a simpler way to store this grid? If needed, the code for my rotation matrix is below:

```
private static Matrix4x4 getRotationMatrix(double x, double y, double z, boolean inverse) {
    double sign = (inverse) ? -1 : 1;
    Matrix4x4 rotateX = new Matrix4x4(new double[][]{
            {1, 0,             0,            0},
            {0, Math.cos(sign * x), -Math.sin(sign * x), 0},
            {0, Math.sin(sign * x),  Math.cos(sign * x), 0},
            {0, 0,             0,            1}
    });
    Matrix4x4 rotateY = new Matrix4x4(new double[][]{
            { Math.cos(sign * y), 0, Math.sin(sign * y), 0},
            { 0,            1, 0,            0},
            {-Math.sin(sign * y), 0, Math.cos(sign * y), 0},
            { 0,            0, 0,            1} 
    });
    Matrix4x4 rotateZ = new Matrix4x4(new double[][]{
            {Math.cos(sign * z), -Math.sin(sign * z), 0, 0},
            {Math.sin(sign * z),  Math.cos(sign * z), 0, 0},
            {0,             0,            1, 0},
            {0,             0,            0, 1}
    });
    Matrix4x4 rotation = rotateZ.multiply(rotateY).multiply(rotateX);
    return rotation;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the rotation around the z-axis. The triangle must be rotated around `rot_axis = cross(tri_normal, z_axis)`, not around the z-axis.

Comment: See [my answer here for details](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15070/orienting-a-model-to-face-a-target/15078#15078). Either use quaternions as in my answer, or [convert the rotation-axis and the rotation-angle (axis-angle) to a matrix using Matrix4x4::CreateFromAxisAngle](https://www.matterhackers.com/static/docs/mattercad/MatterHackers.VectorMath/Matrix4X4.htm#CreateFromAxisAngle)

Comment: Thank you! I went with the Matrix4x4 solution and it worked great. Do you want to write an answer that I can accept?

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation-axis is not the z-axis, it is the cross product of the normal of the triangle and the z-axis:

```
rot_axis = normalize(cross(axis_z, triangle_normal))
```

the rot_angle that you already calculated:

```
rot_angle = acos(dot(axis_z, triangle_normal))
```

Now we have the Axis-Angle of the rotation. You can convert it to a matrix using [Matrix4x4::CreateFromAxisAngle](https://www.matterhackers.com/static/docs/mattercad/MatterHackers.VectorMath/Matrix4X4.htm#CreateFromAxisAngle)