# How can I determine how much I need to rotate an object to face a point?

Tags: game-mechanics

I have an object located at (208,608) in my 480x800 screen (portrait orientation). I can touch anywhere on the screen (where `y < 608`) and I will get `touchX` and `touchY`.

What is the angle I need to apply to my object so the it will face the point (touchX, touchY)?

I tried

```
double alfa = (float) Math.atan2(touchY-608,touchX-208) * 180 / PI;
myObject.setRotation(alfa);`
```

but this doesn't seem to work if I touch one half of my screen. I also think this might be because the point is located in different quadrants reletive to my start point?

The angle I am trying to get is the angle determined by the two points and the horizontal axis from the first point.  What I am trying to do is something like a bow facing my moving finger on the screen. Can anyone help me get the right angle please?

[image]

EDIT: I found the answer:

// Calculates an angle a body has to have to face a certain point in space

```
public static float rotateFromPointToPoint(float pFromPointX,float pFromPointY,float
                pToPointX,float pToPointY) {

        float k1 = (float) (pToPointY - pFromPointY);
        float k2 = (float) (pToPointX - pFromPointX);

        float tan = k1 / k2;

        float angle = (float) Math.atan(tan);
        float rotation = (float) Math.toDegrees(angle);

        if (pToPointX < pFromPointX) {
                rotation = (float) Math.toDegrees(angle) + 180;
        }
        return rotation;
}
```

Maybe someone else will find this usefull.

Comment: you'd better post your answer as an answer, instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to do that.. I have to wait 7 more hours.. but I will np ;)

Comment: Good, you will be upvoted for that: being neat is nice :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate object to face player](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11872/rotate-object-to-face-player)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`atan2` is better than the code you post as an answer. What you need to do to the angle you get from `atan2` will depend on what your drawing API considers to be the angle 0, but it's probably to add or subtract `pi/2`. One of the eight combinations of `{-1, 1} * atan2(dy, dx) + {0, pi/2, pi, -pi/2}` will work, so if you can't figure it out from first principles you could try all eight until you find the right one.